# how show user selected cell of tableview on longpress

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilongpressgesturerecogni

Hello i am adding `UILongPressGesture` in my tableview and i have added successfully but issue is that how to show that cell is selected i mean i want change color of selected cell and when i again do longpress on selected cell than i want to delselect cell

i have try to add long press in my tableview with code and assign delegates on LongPress here is my code

```
 @objc func longPress(_ longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {

            let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tblList)
            if let indexPath = tblList.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {


            }
        }
    }
```

And in `viewDidload()` i am writing this code

```
let longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SMSChatViewController.longPress(_:)))
        longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 // 1 second press
        longPressGesture.delegate = self
        self.tblList.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
```

so from this code i am able to select cell but how to show user that the cell is selected i don't know how to do this

so i just want like that when user is do longpress than cell color change and set as selected and then again do longpress than deselect cell with its original color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about you change just the backgroundColor of the cell, when the longPressGesture is recognized? Something like this:

```
@objc func longPress(_ longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {

            let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tblList)
            if let indexPath = tblList.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
                let cell = tblList.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
                if (cell.isSelected) {
                    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear // or whatever color you need as default
                    cell.setSelected(false, animated: true)
                } else {
                    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                    cell.setSelected(true, animated: true)
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

If you need clarification or i missunderstood a thing let me know and i will edit my answer.

Comment: Okay i got it but what if i want to deselect that cell and change this color thats i am not able to do i hope you are able to understood my question right?

Comment: Thanks Mate Your Answer Work For me !!